# How to use a manually installed python package in Docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have been trying to use the module "bonsai" in my AWS Lambda function. Unfortunately, the module does not work in a Linux Environment via pip installation, therefore I have to manually install it. With that being said I created a Docker Container that will include all the needed modules for my project.

```
MyDESKTOP:~/lambda_container$ ls
Dockerfile bonsai lambda_function.py requirements.txt
```

Currently, in my project directory, the "bonsai" folder includes all the code needed for that module:

```
MyDESKTOP:~/lambda_container/bonsai$ ls
init.py,       active_directory,  ldapclient.py,      ldapreference.py,   pool.py,   utils.py, pycache,       asyncio,            ldapconnection.py,  ldapurl.py,        py.typed,  _bonsai.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so,  errors.py,      ldapdn.py,          ldapvaluelist.py,  tornado _bonsai.py,         geventldapentry.py,      ldif.py,           trio
```

I am calling the module in my lambda_function.py file using `import bonsai`. When I start up my container to test I get this error: `{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'bonsai'"`

Here is my DockerFile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11
COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT} 
COPY bonsai ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
RUN pip install setuptools 
RUN pip install boto3 
RUN pip install cryptography 
RUN pip install ldap3
COPY lambda_function.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
CMD [ "lambda_function.handler" ]
```

In conclusion, How do you properly manually install a Python module in Docker?

Thank Y'all in advance!

I have tried manually installing the module in my docker file. Something similar to this:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY bonsai-master ./

RUN sudo apt install build-essential
RUN sudo apt-get install python3-dev
RUN sudo apt-get install libldap2-dev
RUN sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev
RUN python3.11 setup.py build
RUN sudo python3.11 setup.py install

FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11

COPY bonsai ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT} #this is the folder that is created when bonsai is installed in Linux

RUN pip install setuptools
RUN pip install boto3
RUN pip install cryptography
RUN pip install ldap3

COPY lambda_function.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

CMD [ "lambda_function.handler" ]
```

But this was not working so I completely crossed this option out

Comment: Read through this document, I believe it explains exactly how to do this (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html).  If that doesn't help, include the error you get when running docker build on the above Dockerfile.

Comment: That's the Documentation I've been using. This is the error I get when I run the Docker file above: "ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref de3ebf58-d395-4c5b-a543-8bdd424e0a57::s29x1msv59ngldabt46ba5pmr: "/bonsai": not found"

Comment: What you have in your Dockerfile "should" work; in fact, I recreated your hierarchy and was able to build the image with your Dockerfile.  Can you edit your question and include the full output from the docker build, including the directory you're running the build from?